# Make Intellij IDEA handle global JS variables defined in ESLint config

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, ecmascript-6, eslint

I define some global variables in my project's `.eslintrc`, and this config file is detected correctly by ESLint when I run ESLint as a script.

Now, I would like to configure IntelliJ IDEA so that its JavaScript inspector notices that I have defined these global variables in `.eslintrc`, and doesn't bother me with "Missing import statement" warnings for these variables.

For example, both `ReactDOM` and `React` are global variables defined in my `.eslintrc`, so I would like the warnings in this screenshot to disappear:

[image: Missing import statement screenshot]

FYI, the JavaScript language version selected in the project settings is "React JSX (JSX in ECMAScript 6)".

As far as I know, ESlint is configured correctly in the settings:

[image: IntelliJ IDEA Settings screenshot]

What am I missing?

(I am using the currently latest version of IntelliJ IDEA: 2016.3.4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ESLint configuration doesn't affect IDEA own inspections; you need to suppress 'Missing Import statement' inspection using `Alt+Enter`, `Right`, `'Suppress for statement'`;

there is a feature request to respect `env` and `globals` from `.eslintrc` - see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21957

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off the inspections by hand that generate the above message.
The one you are looking for is found here:

- Go to preferences, and select Editor > Inspections
- Type "missing" in the search field
- Click the "collapse all" icon next to the search field and find the root node of JavaScript (with the ▶︎ in front)
- Under "General" is "Missing import statement"; Uncheck it
- You might want to uncheck others..

If you use a well configured eslint and .editorconfig you arguably don't need IDEA's own inspections for Javascript at all. I have it setup like this:

- Backup your project `.idea` folder (it's hidden, found in the root of your project)
- Go to preferences, and select Editor > Inspections
- Click the "collapse all" icon next to the search field and find the root node of JavaScript (with the ▶︎ in front)
- Click the checkbox directly to the right of it, so all JavaScript inspections are OFF
- Now scroll down a bit until you see `Code quality tools` and `ESlint`
- Select the checkbox to the right. Now ESLint is your only active JS inspection.
- In the top-left of the Preferences window, type `editorconfig` and make sure you have the plugin active, together with an [.editorconfig file](http://editorconfig.org/).
- Apply and OK